# ecs-cli up command - attaching own instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

How can I attach my own instance profile to command `ecs-cli up`?

By default there is created an instance profile with default policy `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role`

How can I pass my own policy to this instance during ecs cluster creation phase so it won't use default one?

Answer (score 0):

The ecs-cli does not have that capability. [across a few of their issues and PR's it has been mentioned](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli) but it does not look like that repo gets a lot of love. You might look at using the [well maintained AWS-CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to do this in pieces.